# crystal report Image or QR Code not appear

Tags: crystal-reports

need to show Qr Code from database in crystal report

image code are stored in sql table

apart from the image other fields are displayed

[image: screenshot; missing image icon]

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to use an online service like the Google API.

In Crystal Reports you can :

1. Insert a picture
2. Edit the conditional formula associated with the picture's Graphic
   Location property
3. Provide a link that will generate the QR code. For example:
   "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" +
   {table.field1} + "," + {table.field2}

Answer (score 0):

Please Google Crystal Reports and QR Code.
There are many options.

Also, it's not clear what "image code are stored in sql table" means.

Comment: hi... We Upload image (qr Code) from 1 form... so that image will be stored in sql table.... after that we need to show in crystal report

Answer (score 0):

If the binary column stores the image as one of the typical formats supported by Crystal, you can simply drag that column onto the Crystal report design canvas and it will be displayed in preview.

I believe the supported image types include JPG, BMP, TIF, and PNG.
If the image format is not one those, you would need to convert.